# Динамическое изменение высоты элемента на css

Tags: css, less

Добрый день.

Как сделать динамический css?

Мне нужно сделать высоту элемента div, равную максимальной высоте минус 50px,
что-то типа `style="height:100%-50px "`.

Как это сделать на css?
С помощью less такое делается?

Спасибо.

Comment: > как это сделать на css?

[CSS3](http://htmlbook.ru/css/calc)

CSS2: хак делается за счет height: 100%, положительного padding-top (50px) и отрицательного margin-top(-50px). В результате блок сдвигается вверх, в то время как его контент получает такой же отступ вниз. Возможно, потребуются дополнительные врапперы.

> с помощью less такое делается?

Нет, less не может рассчитать 100% в финальном документе. Он его не видит, он просто собирает правила.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день. При помощи css calc.

```
height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

Пробел между арифметическими знаками и значениями обязателен.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Только в Opera Mini не работает.